# How do I fix the error npm run dev gives?

Tags: javascript, html

Once I use `npm install` it works normally then when I use `npm run dev`, it gives me this:

[image]

here is the code: https://github.com/moigonzalez/pwa-barcode-scanner

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen? You're not actually running those commands in the directory you just cloned to.

Comment: You are not in the repository according to the screen shot. Go inside to the cloned project & run `npm install` & `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run `npm run dev`, you should be inside the cloned repository. According to the screenshot, you cloned the repository but didn't navigate to the repository. Try navigating into the repository and running the command

```
cd pwa-barcode-scanner
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: Thank You, I am so new to this I knowiit is so stupid of me not read intructions well, basically when I enter the app I am supposed to be able to view it in the browser from the file index.html but once I open it it is just a  blank page , could you help me with this?

Comment: If you can add it as a new question with more description, we can help you :)